# Options for taking payments by credit card in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to know my options for letting users make payments in my iPhone application for goods in an e-Commerce store. This will be an app rather than a mobile website.

Ideally, I would just like to use Authorize.net or SagePay - is this possible? I found some posts from a year ago saying that Apple only allow their In App purchase, is this still true?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to Apple's developer member center, have a look at the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), section 11.

To my understanding it is allowed (or required even) to have your own payment-system, as long as you're not selling (digital) items that are supposed to be used in the App.

Comment: It's not massively clear: "11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected" - does this mean buying physical goods but not using IAP is OK?

Comment: Agreed, not crystal clear. The eBay App has PayPal integration, so that seems to be okay.